# web.py mysql query cache

Tags: python, mysql, caching

I have a sql select query which takes about 20 seconds, I want to use mysql cache to cache result so I can quickly get results.

After doing some configuration in my.cnf, I succeed achieving this when run select query in Linux mysql client console.

the added lines in my.cnf is:

```
 query_cache_size = 268435456
 query_cache_type = 1
 query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

But when I run the query from web.py code. The cache function seems not working, that is, the execution time is not shorter than before.

Below is the web.py code:

```
import web      
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='RLCM', user='guest', pw='guest')   
sql = "SELECT xxx from xx"   
results = db.query(sql);
```

Do I need to add any parameters to enable cache?

I solved this issue by excuting SET autocommit=1 before running the query. Now the code is:

```
import web      
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='RLCM', user='guest', pw='guest')   

sql = "SET autocommit=1;"
db.query(sql);

sql = "SELECT xxx from xx"   
results = db.query(sql);
```

Comment: what have you done to make the result cached in mysql client console?

Comment: I add following lines to my.cnf:                              query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your mysql server after you change the `my.cnf` file?

Here is a brief process which can help you identify where is the problem:

1.Make sure the query cache is ON.

```
sql> show variables like '%query_cache%'
have_query_cache      YES
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size     1048576
query_cache_type     ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate      OFF
```

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html
You always get `have_query_cache YES` using standard binary. but the `query_cache_type` field is a indicator.

2.check the status of cache

```
sql> show status like 'Qcache%'

enter code here
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  1026208
Qcache_hits 1
Qcache_inserts  1
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   2
Qcache_queries_in_cache 1
Qcache_total_blocks 4
```

Every time you send a query, if the cache works, the `Qcache_hits` should +1, otherwise the `not_cached` should +1.

3.If the cache is ON and somehow you cannot get the cached result, you might need to learn about how MySQL's cache works: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html

NOTE: You might want to run these SQLs using your web.py environment and mysql console. If you see different results, some cached related settings might be different. Why? Since these SQLs are executed in different sessions, MySQL can set some configurations in session level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have restarted mysql server. But cache query only works when I run query in Linux mysql client console. Just like you said, web.py sql query may execute in different session and there maybe some configuration differences. So I guess there maybe some code missing in my web.py code but I don't what is missed

Comment: If you ran these SQLs used to inspect cache status, and it did report that the cache is OFF, you might want try run another SQL `set session query_cache_type = ON` to see if it helps.